# php loop textfield through listbox

Tags: php

How to make for loop textfield where the textfield is based on listbox given and I want the code run in the same page. For example, if in listbox value is 10 then 10 textfield will come out.

Here is my code:

```
<select name="number">
<?php
  echo '<option value="10">10</option>';
  echo '<option value="20">20</option>';
  echo '<option value="30">30</option>';
?>
</select>
<?php 
for ($i=0; $i<=$_POST["number"]; $i++)
{
    echo '<input type=text/>;
}
?>
```

Comment: *'I want the code run in the same page'* -- Looks like you need AJAX

Comment: you need to select first seletct box based on that you need to create input box. You need to use jquey/javascript or you need to take data from database then ajax is the best solution

Comment: Is a page reload acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

here is my code for your case :

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
<select name="number">
<?php
    echo '<option value="10">10</option>';
    echo '<option value="20">20</option>';
    echo '<option value="30">30</option>';
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']){ 
    for ($i=0; $i<=$_POST["number"]; $i++)
    {
        echo "<input type='text' name='text[$i]'/>";
    }

}
?>
```